# One or two words for a person with blind spots?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We all know people with blind spots. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blind+spot characterizes blind spots as follows:

> **blind spot** - a subject about which you are ignorant or prejudiced and fail to exercise good judgment

People with blind spots can be their own worst enemies. They simply can't see themselves as others see them. They don't see or understand the impacts of their behaviors. And worst of all, their blind spots can make it very difficult to get through to them; they can't see it because they can't see it.  Is there a single word for such a person? If not, a two-word phrase?

Comment: I'd say it is a form of bias, therefore: 'biased', maybe 'topically biased'?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, ***blinkered*** works here.

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blinkered):

> **blinkered**
> *adjective* ​
>
> A blinkered person is unable or unwilling to understand other people's beliefs, and blinkered opinions or ways of behaving
> show someone is unable or unwilling to understand other people:
>
> He's
> very blinkered in his outlook.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinkered):

> *Adjective*
> **blinkered** ‎(comparative more blinkered, superlative most blinkered)
>
> (*figuratively*) Having **tunnel vision**; unable to see what is happening
> around one.